# Compare and delete larger video files in 2 directories

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, diff

I have been converting all of my home videos to HEVC and sometimes the files end up smaller and sometimes they don't. I am currently comparing all the video files manually and it takes forever.

I was wondering if there is a script that can check the 2 folders and delete the larger of the 2 files and keep the smaller one.

After all I am doing this to save space. I do all my conversion in Ubuntu 17.04 CLI so a bash script would be preferable but I am not a scripter.

Comment: Why rsync tag?
It does not matter if it's Ubuntu or Gentoo. You want to compare file sizes in linux.
Please fill in details about your directory structure and naming conventions for files (same name, different directory?)

Comment: I have the original videos in one directory and the converted in another directory. The filenames are always the same but sometimes the extension may vary. I tried researching how to accomplish this before I posted and I found allot of people recommending rsync. This is why I used rsync tag.

Comment: So, your common ground is filename (without extension). You are sure there is no file with the same name but different extension in either directories?

Comment: Sometimes the original will have a different extension than the output. The destination output file will always have the .mkv extension but the original may have .avi, .mpg etc. But the filenames themselves will always match.

Comment: Is this not possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `zsh` (`sudo apt-get install zsh` if not already installed):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
typeset -A files
for f in **/*.*(.LM+50oL); do
  if (($+files[$f:t:r])); then
    printf '"%s" was smaller than "%s"\n' $files[$f:t:r] $f
    ls -lUd -- $files[$f:t:r] $f
    rm -i -- $f
  else
    files[$f:t:r]=$f
  fi
done
```

That is go through all the more than 50MiB (as typical for videos) files sorted by size, and if a file with the same tail (base name) and root name (that is without the extension) had already been seen before, that means it was smaller, so offer to remove it (with `-i` so you get a chance to refuse).

Example:

```
$ that-script
"foo.mov" was smaller than "foo.avi"
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 62914560 Jun 29 00:08 foo.mov
-rw-r--r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 73400320 Jun 29 00:08 foo.avi
rm: remove regular file 'foo.avi'?
```

Comment: This script doesn't appear to look at the files in 2 separate directories.